# Which directory do images and stylesheets go in for Ruby on Rails HTML pages?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I finished my Ruby on Rails project and I get extra credit for making it "look good." I made an HTML template with some images and css styling on my local machine (not the RoR server). I've tested it out in plain HTML and it looks good.

I can't figure out how to incorporate it into my RoR project though. I thought i'd be able to create a directory in my views, called "images" to hold the images for my template.

Before transferring all of the code for my RoR to the tags for my template, I wanted to make sure the images were in the right location. I added  to my index.html.erb file, but it won't display. I tried moving that images directory to a few other directories and tried again, same thing!

I thought it would be easy to incorporate a template haha but now I'm thinking not?

Is there a way to simply do this like an ordinary HTML website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main options for this...

1. You can use [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and serve up assets from a location like `app/assets`... So, `app/assets/images`.
2. You can put them in `public/images` and just serve them up that way as well.

If you feel like learning a bit more, I'd dig into the asset pipeline. If you're just ready to be done, `public/images` for a small project should work just fine. :)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much! For the stylesheet.. does it need to be in public/stylesheets/style.css? Or just in public? I usually have it in the same directory as the HTML pages.

Comment: It can be either place in `public` - it'll just change how you access it in your views.

Comment: My pleasure.  Hit the green checkmark next to this answer if you're ready to close out this question. :)

Comment: that is correct but remember that you should use <%= image_tag "myphoto.png" %> in the myview.html.erb to use the asset path. Read all about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html